# Creating a div that knows where the mouse came from, including high mouse speed edge case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/IwoDahe/1/edit?html,css,js,output

### Context

I'm trying to create a "smart" div that knows where the mouse came from, and slides information from that side. Upon exit, it should slide information away in the exited  direction.

This is fairly easy when the mouse moves slowly, as you can use .hover() and .slideToggle() to effectively capture and manipulate mouse movement.

However, when a user moves their mouse very fast, the slideToggle() function blocks the listener for mouseleave while it animates. (Which means the info ends up staying in the div even after mouseleave.) I've resorted to using the CSS :hover pseudoselector, but I'm still hitting an issue:

### Issue

When the side of mouse **entry** is different from the side that the mouse **last exited**, the info slides in from the exited side, **not** the entered side. Check out the JSBin if what I'm saying sounds like total gibberish.

An idea I had was to, upon mouseenter, move the info div to the side that it's **supposed** to enter from, and **then** apply the pseudoselector. Problem is, CSS pseudoselectors fire faster than the JS.

### Tests

***Prepare:*** Widen your screen in JSBin so that the divs form a 4square.

***It's Not Working When:*** enter div from top. info slides down. exit left. info slides left. enter from top. info will slide down from the left. Also, yes even initial entry is buggy.

***It's Working When:*** enter div from left side. info slides in from left. exit top. info slides up. re-enter from left. info slides from left again.

Comment: How about a pure CSS solution? http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/mIxhv

Comment: I thought of doing it thas way while brainstorming. Problem is, I may end up having a large number of imgs I'm trying to do this to, which will end up cluttering up my HTML quite a bit.        



(Then again, that would have helped me avoid cluttered JS, so I guess it's a case of picking your poison?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it by checking whether or not the parent is hovered and changing the switch effect if so

```
switch (slideDirection) {
    case 'top':
        if (parent.is(':hover')) 
            info.css({
                'left': 0,
                'top': -200
            }).stop().animate({
                'left': 0,
                'top': 0
            })
        else 
            info.stop().animate({
                'left': 0,
                'top': -200
            })
        break;
    case 'right':
        if (parent.is(':hover')) 
            info.css({
                'left': 200,
                'top': 0
            }).stop().animate({
                'left': 0,
                'top': 0
            })
        else 
            info.stop().animate({
                'left': 200,
                'top': 0
            })
        break;
    case 'bottom':
        if (parent.is(':hover')) 
            info.css({
                'left': 0,
                'top': 200
            }).stop().animate({
                'left': 0,
                'top': 0
            })
        else 
            info.stop().animate({
                'left': 0,
                'top': 200
            })
        break;
    case 'left':
        if (parent.is(':hover')) 
            info.css({
                'top': 0,
                'left': -200
            }).stop().animate({
                'left': 0,
                'top': 0
            })
        else 
            info.stop().animate({
                'left': -200,
                'top': 0
            })
        break;
}
```

[image: jsFiddle] (Personal preference over jsBin). Sorry the code is a little messy, I'll clean it up when I have more time

**EDIT**

I came across some awesome alternatives to this approach:

- [This demo](http://codepen.io/noeldelgado/pen/pGwFx) shows how jQuery can be combined with CSS transforms to achieve a very similar effect and perhaps more powerful effect
- [Here's a pure CSS version](http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/GrpqB) (awesome) but it does not leave the same direction as the mouse

Comment: This is faaaaaantastic! This project was my first foray into jQuery-controlled CSS shenanigans, didn't think to use .animate()

Comment: Just found something strange--after moving my mouse around the divs a bunch, the animations queue up and keep running long after the I've stopped moving. Unchecking this for now

Comment: @Salar I added some `stop()`s to prevent queuing. Should be fully functional now

Comment: It's adds an interesting effect where if you time the entrance and exit right it will go diagonal at times. Neat effect but if you're looking to not have that effect you might be able to `queue()` the animations but not let the queue get more than one per box

Comment: @Salar You might check out the alternatives I just added